# I see this error ORA-01722: invalid number when I want to insert data to oracle database table

Tags: asp.net, oracle, visual-studio

I want to add answer table but I see error like 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-01722: invalid number '

```
 DateTime localDate = DateTime.Now;
            var culture = new CultureInfo("ru-RU");
            var datenow = localDate.ToString(culture);
            string[] splitdatenow = datenow.Split(' ');    

 cnn.Open();
            OracleCommand cmdu = cnn.CreateCommand();
            cmdu.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ANSWER (EXPLAIN,STATUS,USERID,QUESTIONID,CREATEDATE,MEDIA) VALUES (:comment_forms,'T',(SELECT ID FROM USERS WHERE MAIL=:mailSession) ,:send,:datef,:uploadf)";
            cmdu.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmdu.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":send",OracleDbType.Int32));
            cmdu.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":comment_forms", comment_form));
            cmdu.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":datef", splitdatenow[0]));
            cmdu.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":uploadf", upload_form));
            cmdu.Parameters[":gelenid"].Value = gel;
            cmdu.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":mailSession",mailSession));
            try
            {
                cmdu.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex);
            }
            cnn.Close();
```

Trigger for auto increment

```
create or replace 
trigger ANSWERIDTRIGGER 
BEFORE INSERT ON ANSWER 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  select ANSWERIDSEQ.nextval
        into :new.ID
        from dual;
END;
```

Comment: I changed cmdu.Parameters[":gelenid"].Value = gel; to cmdu.Parameters[":send"].Value = gel; but ıt doesnt insert to table and gel is a number

Comment: Please show the definition of the table in question.